# How to migrate existing SQLite application to Room Persistance Library?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm, android-room

It might be a bit early to ask, but is it possible and how to migrate/upgrade an existing SQLite database application to a new Android Room Persistance Library?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming your room entities match your current table schemas, you can keep using the same database/tables.

Room manages a master table which is initialized on creation or upgrade of the database, so you need to increment your database version and provide a dummy migration:

```
@Database(entities = SomeEntity.class, version = EXISTING_VERSION + 1)
public class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    // ...
}

MyDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase.class, "db_name")
                    .addMigrations(new Migration(EXISTING_VERSION, EXISTING_VERSION + 1) {
                        @Override
                        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                            // NOOP
                        }
                    }).build();
```

Comment: Haven't tested it yet, but I'll mark it as an answer, since database name parameter probably allows you to use any previous and already existing database.

Comment: Do you know a way to test this migration? I've looked at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html#testing but I'm not sure how to test a migration from existing sqlite into room.

Comment: @Gubbel If I use the above dummy migration, can I keep all of my existing SQLite queries in my existing SQLite database class or do I need to somehow migrate them also?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are wondering if there is any way to migrate from `SQLite` to `Room` even if your schema does not match, the answer is **YES**, you can migrate from `SQLite` to room even if the schema does not match.

It is possible, but a requires quite careful conversions. As the process requires so many steps to cover, I will just leave references you can follow.

[Incrementally migrate from SQLite to Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/incrementally-migrate-from-sqlite-to-room-66c2f655b377)

Hope it will be helpful for a few.

Comment: @unexplored removed the duplicate link. I am not able to find the old link, probably it got deleted