# How to use an existing database with an Android application using room ORM with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

My project has some initializes data so I have already create a sqlite database with navicat application. I use kotlin instead of java and use room ORM too (android-architecture-components).
how can i copy my database too my project from asset folder without any problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate existing SQLite application to Room Persistance Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081249/how-to-migrate-existing-sqlite-application-to-room-persistance-library)

Answer (score 0):

referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081249/how-to-migrate-existing-sqlite-application-to-room-persistance-library) question , you have just make sure of having same db schema in order to do that. and to copy file to `/database` folder in internal app storage there is plenty of resources and example just search.